# Obstruction to the existence of lifting of the classifying map

Tags: cohomology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, obstruction-theory, stiefel-whitney

Let $E$ be an $n$-plane bundle over CW complex $X$. Then $E$ is a pullback of tautological bundle $\gamma_n$ over $BO(n)$ i.e. $E=f^*(\gamma_n)$. This $f$ is called classyfing map. One can show that the universal covering of $BO(n)$ is $BSO(n)$ and $f$ can be lifted to $BSO(n)$ (meaning that there is $\tilde{f}:X \to BSO(n)$ such that $p \circ \tilde{f}=f$ where $p$ is the projection) if and only if $f_*:\pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(BO(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ is zero. Such a map from $\pi_1(X)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gives rise to the cohomology class in $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

One can also show that the $2$-connected covering of $BSO(n)$ is $BSpin(n)$ and one can ask for further extensions of the classyfing map to $BSpin(n)$.

> I would like to understand how the existence of such extension is equivalent to the vanishing of some class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

I know that this class should be exactly the second Stiefel-Whitney class and I would also like to understand:

> Why this class is the second Stiefel-Whitney class?

Comment: One approach is to show $H^*(BO(n); \mathbb F_2)\cong \mathbb F_2[w_1, w_2, \dotsc]$, where $\lvert w_i\rvert = i$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ Stiefel-Whitney class, i.e. $w_i(E) = f^*(w_i)$. Because $BSO(n)$ is simply connected, the pullback $H^*(BO(n); \mathbb F_2)\to H^*(BSO(n); \mathbb F_2)$ must send $w_1\mapsto 0$, and you can show that everything else is preserved: $H^*(BSO(n); \mathbb F_2)\cong \mathbb F_2[w_2, w_3, \dotsc]$.

Comment: The next step is that the pullback $H^*(BSO(n); \mathbb F_2)\to H^*(\mathit{BSpin}(n); \mathbb F_2)$ sends $w_2\mapsto 0$ and is otherwise an isomorphism. Thus a spin structure implies the vanishing of $w_2$, though these computations are nontrivial!

Comment: (Sorry, just had to correct the spelling of "classifying"...)

Comment: This is because the map $BSpin(n)→BSO(n)$ is the (homotopy) fiber of the second Stiefel-Whitney class map $BSO(n)→K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$. This can be proved roughly as Arun Debray indicates, basically it involves identifying the k-invariants for $BO$ in low degrees.